# Flex Boxes left align effect

Tags: html, css

I'm wanting to achieve a footer which will always be at the bottom of my page. I'm using flex boxes to get the basics of this effect but I cannot seem to align the elements the way I want. I would thankful for any help.

I'm still a student and much better at web development than design. But, both must be mastered if I'm to get anywhere. I'm doing this project as part of a portfolio and for practice.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.content {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}

.footer {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head></head>

<body>
  <div class="content">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur sagittis massa justo, eget elementum orci efficitur sit amet. Sed eget iaculis odio. Aenean aliquet elit tellus, id luctus ex efficitur in. Quisque eu eros dui. Sed a arcu in leo hendrerit
    convallis vel sit amet purus. Aenean ac libero non nisl dapibus faucibus vel id elit. Suspendisse sed dictum erat, non posuere risus. Nulla fermentum, neque a vehicula sodales, massa arcu sagittis nunc, vel euismod lorem libero a elit. In auctor vehicula
    porta. Morbi vitae tristique enim. Phasellus at elit scelerisque, dignissim odio vitae, fermentum tellus. Maecenas pretium mollis metus non hendrerit. Ut mollis elementum lorem et semper. Nam ornare, mauris id maximus semper, mi lorem interdum risus,
    mollis rutrum ex mi pharetra tellus. Ut vitae mattis lacus, vitae scelerisque enim. Maecenas dictum quis nisl vitae condimentum. Pellentesque pulvinar sem nec risus dignissim, sed egestas libero mollis. Maecenas iaculis suscipit justo, vel rutrum
    leo auctor in. Integer condimentum purus in placerat viverra. Ut euismod enim ut erat aliquet feugiat ac vel ante. Pellentesque mollis diam lacinia augue maximus, iaculis congue nisl dapibus. Integer consectetur nibh sapien. Cras at risus lorem. Suspendisse
    venenatis eleifend erat quis fringilla. Aliquam gravida lacus et leo tempor porttitor. Aliquam placerat felis laoreet condimentum viverra. Nulla at bibendum est. Nunc mattis pharetra nunc vitae interdum. Maecenas suscipit molestie vehicula. Nulla
    sed diam pretium, lacinia leo tincidunt, porttitor nulla. Ut nec massa imperdiet, maximus turpis vel, posuere nisi. Mauris ut purus purus. Mauris rhoncus diam sit amet imperdiet volutpat. Cras vitae risus sem. Aenean sed mi eget lorem laoreet pretium
    sit amet non turpis. Nulla vel maximus tortor. Nunc auctor diam laoreet pulvinar posuere. Mauris nec lectus eget massa tincidunt tempus. Etiam viverra justo diam, a vulputate lectus efficitur et. Suspendisse tellus justo, bibendum at vehicula id,
    bibendum id nisl. Donec dictum ex ac orci accumsan sollicitudin. Phasellus aliquet lorem non egestas facilisis. Ut vehicula et augue vitae tempus. Integer pellentesque sed nulla in pharetra. In scelerisque ex vel ipsum congue posuere. Donec accumsan
    finibus eleifend. Donec leo ipsum, placerat id faucibus ut, commodo eget purus. Sed tellus massa, vehicula in sem at, bibendum tristique sem. Mauris vulputate ligula at tortor vestibulum consectetur. Cras ultricies tortor lorem, id congue arcu pretium
    eget. In velit erat, luctus a neque et, placerat elementum nunc. Nulla a mauris tempus, blandit ante at, condimentum libero.
  </div>
  <footer class="footer">
    <!-- Footer Links -->
    <div class="container text-center text-md-left">

      <!-- Grid row -->
      <div class="row">

        <!-- Grid column -->
        <div class="col-md-3 mx-auto">

          <!-- Links -->
          <h5 class="font-weight-bold text-uppercase mt-3 mb-4">Links</h5>

          <ul class="list-unstyled">
            <li>
              <a href="#!">Very long link 1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#!">Very long link 2</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#!">Very long link 3</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#!">Very long link 4</a>
            </li>
          </ul>

        </div>
        <!-- Grid column -->

        <hr class="clearfix w-100 d-md-none">

        <!-- Grid column -->
        <div class="col-md-3 mx-auto">

          <!-- Links -->
          <h5 class="font-weight-bold text-uppercase mt-3 mb-4">Links</h5>

          <ul class="list-unstyled">
            <li>
              <a href="#!">Link 1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#!">Link 2</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#!">Link 3</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#!">Link 4</a>
            </li>
          </ul>

        </div>
        <!-- Grid column -->

        <hr class="clearfix w-100 d-md-none">

        <!-- Grid column -->
        <div class="col-md-3 mx-auto">

          <!-- Links -->
          <h5 class="font-weight-bold text-uppercase mt-3 mb-4">Links</h5>

          <ul class="list-unstyled">
            <li>
              <a href="#!">Link 1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#!">Link 2</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#!">Link 3</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#!">Link 4</a>
            </li>
          </ul>

        </div>
        <!-- Grid column -->

        <hr class="clearfix w-100 d-md-none">

        <!-- Grid column -->
        <div class="col-md-3 mx-auto">

          <!-- Links -->
          <h5 class="font-weight-bold text-uppercase mt-3 mb-4">Links</h5>

          <ul class="list-unstyled">
            <li>
              <a href="#!">Link 1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#!">Link 2</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#!">Link 3</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#!">Link 4</a>
            </li>
          </ul>

        </div>
        <!-- Grid column -->

      </div>
      <!-- Grid row -->

    </div>
    <!-- Footer Links -->

    <!-- Copyright -->
    <div class="footer-copyright text-center py-3">© 2018 Copyright:
      <a href="https://mdbootstrap.com/education/bootstrap/"> MDBootstrap.com</a>
    </div>
    <!-- Copyright -->
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

What I expected was that the footer would stick to the bottom of the page. It does this, but the .footer section is still laying out in column format. I know that this is due to the fact that its parent is set to this. But give that I'm working with flex boxes, I'm unsure how to get it to do what I want.

Comment: To use the grid you need to link bootstrap: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/introduction/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flexbox rules aren't inherited, they only affect the container itself and only its direct descendants become flex-items. 
The stacking you are seeing is because your `div` containers and `hr` elements are block elements and take the full width by default.

Your markup is fine and just works (on full screen) after you add bootstrap.  You can refer to the [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/) or the source for more detail, but as an outline just in case you want to roll your own version without bootstrap:

- `row` creates a flex container. Equivalent to `display: flex;`.
- `col-x` creates a column x wide out of 12. For your case, `col-3` is equivalent to `width: 25%;` (or `flex-basis: 25%;` to maintain flexbox style)
- `-md-`, `-xs-` apply only for specific breakpoints.

Just adding a couple of rules should fix your issue. Note that `.row` sets `display: flex;` but no `flex-direction` and still flows in row. If you remove that `display`, the links still stack in columns because of the `hr` elements being `100%` width and the `div` elements are not floated.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.content {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}

.footer {
  background-color: black;
}

.col-md-3 {
  width: 25%;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<html>


<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="content">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur sagittis massa justo, eget elementum orci efficitur sit amet. Sed eget iaculis odio. Aenean aliquet elit tellus, id luctus ex efficitur in. Quisque eu eros dui. Sed a arcu in leo hendrerit
    convallis vel sit amet purus. Aenean ac libero non nisl dapibus faucibus vel id elit. Suspendisse sed dictum erat, non posuere risus. Nulla fermentum, neque a vehicula sodales, massa arcu sagittis nunc, vel euismod lorem libero a elit. In auctor vehicula
    porta. Morbi vitae tristique enim. Phasellus at elit scelerisque, dignissim odio vitae, fermentum tellus. Maecenas pretium mollis metus non hendrerit. Ut mollis elementum lorem et semper. Nam ornare, mauris id maximus semper, mi lorem interdum risus,
    mollis rutrum ex mi pharetra tellus. Ut vitae mattis lacus, vitae scelerisque enim. Maecenas dictum quis nisl vitae condimentum. Pellentesque pulvinar sem nec risus dignissim, sed egestas libero mollis. Maecenas iaculis suscipit justo, vel rutrum
    leo auctor in. Integer condimentum purus in placerat viverra. Ut euismod enim ut erat aliquet feugiat ac vel ante. Pellentesque mollis diam lacinia augue maximus, iaculis congue nisl dapibus. Integer consectetur nibh sapien. Cras at risus lorem. Suspendisse
    venenatis eleifend erat quis fringilla. Aliquam gravida lacus et leo tempor porttitor. Aliquam placerat felis laoreet condimentum viverra. Nulla at bibendum est. Nunc mattis pharetra nunc vitae interdum. Maecenas suscipit molestie vehicula. Nulla
    sed diam pretium, lacinia leo tincidunt, porttitor nulla. Ut nec massa imperdiet, maximus turpis vel, posuere nisi. Mauris ut purus purus. Mauris rhoncus diam sit amet imperdiet volutpat. Cras vitae risus sem. Aenean sed mi eget lorem laoreet pretium
    sit amet non turpis. Nulla vel maximus tortor. Nunc auctor diam laoreet pulvinar posuere. Mauris nec lectus eget massa tincidunt tempus. Etiam viverra justo diam, a vulputate lectus efficitur et. Suspendisse tellus justo, bibendum at vehicula id,
    bibendum id nisl. Donec dictum ex ac orci accumsan sollicitudin. Phasellus aliquet lorem non egestas facilisis. Ut vehicula et augue vitae tempus. Integer pellentesque sed nulla in pharetra. In scelerisque ex vel ipsum congue posuere. Donec accumsan
    finibus eleifend. Donec leo ipsum, placerat id faucibus ut, commodo eget purus. Sed tellus massa, vehicula in sem at, bibendum tristique sem. Mauris vulputate ligula at tortor vestibulum consectetur. Cras ultricies tortor lorem, id congue arcu pretium
    eget. In velit erat, luctus a neque et, placerat elementum nunc. Nulla a mauris tempus, blandit ante at, condimentum libero.
  </div>
  <footer class="footer">
    <!-- Footer Links -->
    <div class="container text-center text-md-left">

      <!-- Grid row -->
      <div class="row">

        <!-- Grid column -->
        <div class="col-md-3 mx-auto">

          <!-- Links -->
          <h5 class="font-weight-bold text-uppercase mt-3 mb-4">Links</h5>

          <ul class="list-unstyled">
            <li>
              <a href="#!">Very long link 1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#!">Very long link 2</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#!">Very long link 3</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#!">Very long link 4</a>
            </li>
          </ul>

        </div>
        <!-- Grid column -->

        <hr class="clearfix w-100 d-md-none">

        <!-- Grid column -->
        <div class="col-md-3 mx-auto">

          <!-- Links -->
          <h5 class="font-weight-bold text-uppercase mt-3 mb-4">Links</h5>

          <ul class="list-unstyled">
            <li>
              <a href="#!">Link 1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#!">Link 2</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#!">Link 3</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#!">Link 4</a>
            </li>
          </ul>

        </div>
        <!-- Grid column -->

        <hr class="clearfix w-100 d-md-none">

        <!-- Grid column -->
        <div class="col-md-3 mx-auto">

          <!-- Links -->
          <h5 class="font-weight-bold text-uppercase mt-3 mb-4">Links</h5>

          <ul class="list-unstyled">
            <li>
              <a href="#!">Link 1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#!">Link 2</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#!">Link 3</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#!">Link 4</a>
            </li>
          </ul>

        </div>
        <!-- Grid column -->

        <hr class="clearfix w-100 d-md-none">

        <!-- Grid column -->
        <div class="col-md-3 mx-auto">

          <!-- Links -->
          <h5 class="font-weight-bold text-uppercase mt-3 mb-4">Links</h5>

          <ul class="list-unstyled">
            <li>
              <a href="#!">Link 1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#!">Link 2</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#!">Link 3</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#!">Link 4</a>
            </li>
          </ul>

        </div>
        <!-- Grid column -->

      </div>
      <!-- Grid row -->

    </div>
    <!-- Footer Links -->

    <!-- Copyright -->
    <div class="footer-copyright text-center py-3">© 2018 Copyright:
      <a href="https://mdbootstrap.com/education/bootstrap/"> MDBootstrap.com</a>
    </div>
    <!-- Copyright -->
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I've got so much to learn. I'll implement this right away.

Comment: Also, can you tell me exactly what is causing the footer to stick to the bottom?

Comment: @CuiBono It is the last element in a column flow and `.content` has `flex-grow` so it's filling the body to the `100%` specified. It has no other place to go. Even if they were on another order or `.content` didn't grow, you could still achieve this with `flex-order` and `justify-self` properties.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that using a flexbox would be the best method to place a footer.

If you are trying to keep the footer at the bottom of the viewport, this would work:

```
footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

If you mean a sticky footer which stays at the bottom, check out [this article](https://css-tricks.com/couple-takes-sticky-footer/).

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want with just flexbox and you don't need all the bootstrap classes.

Here is a very simplified version of what I believe you are looking for:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.content {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  padding: 20px;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.footer {
  background-color: grey;
  padding: 20px;
}

.footer__container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

footer a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.footer__headings{
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}

.footer__list {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <main class="content">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur sagittis massa justo, eget elementum orci efficitur sit amet. Sed eget iaculis odio. Aenean aliquet elit tellus, id luctus ex efficitur in. Quisque eu eros dui. Sed a arcu in leo hendrerit
    convallis vel sit amet purus. Aenean ac libero non nisl dapibus faucibus vel id elit. Suspendisse sed dictum erat, non posuere risus. Nulla fermentum, neque a vehicula sodales, massa arcu sagittis nunc, vel euismod lorem libero a elit. In auctor vehicula
    porta. Morbi vitae tristique enim. Phasellus at elit scelerisque, dignissim odio vitae, fermentum tellus. Maecenas pretium mollis metus non hendrerit. Ut mollis elementum lorem et semper. Nam ornare, mauris id maximus semper, mi lorem interdum risus,
    mollis rutrum ex mi pharetra tellus. Ut vitae mattis lacus, vitae scelerisque enim. Maecenas dictum quis nisl vitae condimentum. Pellentesque pulvinar sem nec risus dignissim, sed egestas libero mollis. Maecenas iaculis suscipit justo, vel rutrum
    leo auctor in. Integer condimentum purus in placerat viverra. Ut euismod enim ut erat aliquet feugiat ac vel ante. Pellentesque mollis diam lacinia augue maximus, iaculis congue nisl dapibus. Integer consectetur nibh sapien. Cras at risus lorem. Suspendisse
    venenatis eleifend erat quis fringilla. Aliquam gravida lacus et leo tempor porttitor. Aliquam placerat felis laoreet condimentum viverra. Nulla at bibendum est. Nunc mattis pharetra nunc vitae interdum. Maecenas suscipit molestie vehicula. Nulla
    sed diam pretium, lacinia leo tincidunt, porttitor nulla. Ut nec massa imperdiet, maximus turpis vel, posuere nisi. Mauris ut purus purus. Mauris rhoncus diam sit amet imperdiet volutpat. Cras vitae risus sem. Aenean sed mi eget lorem laoreet pretium
    sit amet non turpis. Nulla vel maximus tortor. Nunc auctor diam laoreet pulvinar posuere. Mauris nec lectus eget massa tincidunt tempus. Etiam viverra justo diam, a vulputate lectus efficitur et. Suspendisse tellus justo, bibendum at vehicula id,
    bibendum id nisl. Donec dictum ex ac orci accumsan sollicitudin. Phasellus aliquet lorem non egestas facilisis. Ut vehicula et augue vitae tempus. Integer pellentesque sed nulla in pharetra. In scelerisque ex vel ipsum congue posuere. Donec accumsan
    finibus eleifend. Donec leo ipsum, placerat id faucibus ut, commodo eget purus. Sed tellus massa, vehicula in sem at, bibendum tristique sem. Mauris vulputate ligula at tortor vestibulum consectetur. Cras ultricies tortor lorem, id congue arcu pretium
    eget. In velit erat, luctus a neque et, placerat elementum nunc. Nulla a mauris tempus, blandit ante at, condimentum libero.
  </main>
  <footer class="footer">
    <div class="footer__container">

        <ul class="footer__list">
          <li>
            <h5 class="footer__headings">Links 1</h5>  
          </li>            
          <li>
            <a href="#!">Very long link 1</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#!">Very long link 2</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#!">Very long link 3</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#!">Very long link 4</a>
          </li>
        </ul>

        <ul class="footer__list">
          <li>
            <h5 class="footer__headings">Links 2</h5>  
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#!">Link 1</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#!">Link 2</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#!">Link 3</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#!">Link 4</a>
          </li>
        </ul>

        <ul class="footer__list">
          <li>
            <h5 class="footer__headings">Links 3</h5>  
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#!">Link 1</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#!">Link 2</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#!">Link 3</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#!">Link 4</a>
          </li>
        </ul>

        <ul class="footer__list">
          <li>
            <h5 class="footer__headings">Links 4</h5>  
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#!">Link 1</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#!">Link 2</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#!">Link 3</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#!">Link 4</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

or on codepen https://codepen.io/davidysoards/pen/YogBGB?editors=1100